# How to implement differentiable hamming loss in pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, loss-function, hamming-distance, differentiation

How to implement a differentiable loss function that counts the number of wrong predictions?

```
output = [1,0,4,10]
target = [1,2,4,15]
loss = np.count_nonzero(output != target) / len(output) # [0,1,0,1] -> 2 / 4 -> 0.5
```

[image]

I have tried a few implementations but they are not differentiable. `RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn`

```
def hamming_loss(output, target):
  #loss = torch.tensor(torch.nonzero(output != target).size(0)).double() / target.size(0)
  #loss = torch.sum((output != target), dim=0).double() / target.size(0)
  loss = torch.mean((output != target).double())
  return loss
```

Maybe there is some similar but differential loss function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you convert your discrete predictions (e.g., `[1, 0, 4, 10]`) with "soft" predictions, i.e. probability of each label (e.g., `output` becomes a 4x(num labels) probability vectors).
Once you have "soft" predictions, you can compute the cross entropy loss between the predicted output probabilities and the desired targets.

Comment: thank you, it works. My final layer: nn.Linear(128, Number_Of_Classes *Size_Of_Predictions). Then x.view(x.size(0), Number_Of_Classes, Size_Of_Predictions) + CrossEntropyLoss

Comment: Hi, @Shai could you clarify the solution with some working piece of code? I didn't get how this idea includes Hamming loss, since that was the initial idea.
thank you

Comment: @mark My idea does **not** include Hamming loss. In fact, you cannot use Hamming loss as a criterion for optimizing a model's weights with Stochastic Gradient Descend (SGD): The gradient of the Hamming loss is zero almost everywhere. Therefore, you must use a "proxy loss", e.g., cross entropy.

Comment: @Shai. Thank you. I understand. Do you have some suggestions on what to do in case we do need to implement some kind of distance metric as s loss function/penalization/at least as a part of loss function before cross-entropy loss? Hamming would be the simplest example.
thank you

Comment: @Shai Could you give example with working code for the suggested solution (conversion of discrete predictions) and applying cross-entropy loss? thank you

Comment: @OlegDats Could you explain how that solution with nn.Linear(128, Number_Of_Classes *Size_Of_Predictions). Then x.view(x.size(0), Number_Of_Classes, Size_Of_Predictions) + CrossEntropyLoss solves the problem as expected of initial Hamming loss approach? Could you put please elaborate on the code? thank you